# In Jest, mock a Node module that's in a user module, in a test block

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a user module called `files.js`. It uses the [globby](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby) Node module, like so:

```
const globby = require('globby');

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Get the paths for files in the current directory.
   * 
   * @returns {Promise<string[]>} The file paths.
   */
  async getFiles() {
    return await globby(__dirname);
  },
};
```

I have a `files.test.js` test file, like so:

```
const globby = require('globby');
const path = require('path');

const files = require('./files');

describe('files', () => {
  test('get files', async () => {
    const items = await files.getFiles();

    // The files that we expect are the ones in the current directory. Prepend
    // the current directory to each filename, so that they are absolute paths.
    const expectedFiles = ['files.js', 'files.test.js'];
    const expected = expectedFiles.map((file) => path.join(__dirname, file));

    expect(items).toEqual(expected);
  });

  test('get files (mocked)', async () => {
    // Try to mock the `globby` module.
    jest.mock('globby');

    globby.mockResolvedValue(['Test.js']);

    // Get the files, but expect the mocked value that we just set.
    const items = await files.getFiles();

    expect(items).toEqual(['Test.js']);
  });
});
```

The first test passes fine, but the second test fails, because the resolved value for `globby` failed to mock properly. I've tried this with `jest.mock`, `jest.doMock`, etc. but I am unable to properly mock the value of `globby`, so that it returns `['Test.js']` in the call to `globby` in `getFiles`.

**How can I properly mock the resolved value of `globby` so that it returns what I want in a single test block, from `getFiles`?**

At the moment, I simply split the tests into two files, with one file containing the tests that require `globby` be unmocked, and the other file containing tests that require `globby` be mocked, but I am hoping for a more elegant solution that can do this all in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that I came up with, is the following:

```
const path = require('path');

let files = require('./files');

describe('files', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  test('get files', async () => {
    const items = await files.getFiles();

    // The files that we expect are the ones in the current directory. Prepend
    // the current directory to each filename, so that they are absolute paths.
    const expectedFiles = ['files.js', 'files.test.js'];
    const expected = expectedFiles.map((file) => path.join(__dirname, file));

    expect(items).toEqual(expected);
  });

  test('get files (mocked)', async () => {
    jest.doMock('globby');

    const globby = require('globby');
    files = require('./files');

    globby.mockResolvedValue(['Test.js']);

    // Get the files, but expect the mocked value that we just set.
    const items = await files.getFiles();

    expect(items).toEqual(['Test.js']);
  });
});
```